# How to add elementary tweaks PPA?

Tags: ppa

I have been adding a PPA but but it returns to errors as follows

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily
[sudo] password for maddys: 
Usage: lsb_release [options]

lsb_release: error: no such option: -u
Usage: lsb_release [options]

lsb_release: error: no such option: -u
Usage: lsb_release [options]

lsb_release: error: no such option: -u
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I could figure out the problem. Earlier in Linux Mint I used following format to tell apt-get to use proxy authentication. But it seems to not work in eOS.

> export http_proxy=http:"//username:userpass@proxy:port"

Then I tried my luck my changing a little as follows by removing quotes and using slash.

> export http_proxy=http://username:userpass@proxy:port/
>   sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily

Answer (score 0):

Elementary Tweaks is dead as far as I know. They probably took the ppa down.

Comment: Thanks for lending help... but I was majorly concerned about adding PPAs. I couldnt add any PPA. Anyhow I figured out the problem. Problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could install it with https://github.com/Devil505/elementaryos-postinstall script.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the PPA wrong. Try ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks